# Optimizing query: DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL (Oracle)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I want to get all table definition for all my tables.
And I want to do it fast (it is part of a script that I'm running a lot)

I am using oracle 11g, and I have 700 tables. On a plain jdbc code it takes 4 minutes and does:

```
s = con.statement("select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(object_type,object_name) from user_objects where object_type = 'TABLE');
s.execute();
rs = s.getResultSet();
while(rs.next()){
 rs.getString(1);
}
```

SO I want to optimize this code and reach around 20 sec.

I have already reached 40-50 sec by creating 14 threads that each opens a connection to the database and reads a part of the information, using mod on the rownum.

But this is not enough.

I am thinking in these directions:

1. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/connpoca.htm#1063660 - connection caching. can it help speed up things by replacing my 14 connections with connectionCaching?
2. Is it possible to keep the tables accessed by this function, in the KEEP buffer cache area?
3. Anyway of indexing some of the information here?
4. Any other suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: This sounds like the kind of question you would only ask if you're not using version control.  If that's the case, the real answer is: use version control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no easy to make it faster. The whole GET_DDL thing is implemented in Java and uses XSLT transformation as a part of generation process.

Maybe you will find this faster.
http://metacpan.org/pod/DDL::Oracle

Comment: I'd be very, very careful with suggesting 3rd party tools for this task - especially one that apparently hasn't been updated in a few years (so it will certainly *not* support new features like column default values using sequences etc.)

Comment: Yes you're right. On the other hand DBMS_METADATA also has(or had) it's gotchas and also it does not work in XE editions. It does not work on any other database installation where JVM is missing. Another  way I use a lot is: `EXP FULL=YES ROWS=NO` and then `IMP SHOW=YES`. Then I process the output from imp through hand-made perl script.

Answer (score 5):

Is it required to always get the DDL even if the tables haven't been changed? Otherwise only get the DDL of those tables where ALL_OBJECTS.LAST_DDL_TIME has changed since you last retrieved it.

Another option would be to write your own GET_DDL in a way that is able to get more than one table at once.

Answer (score 1):

I would firstly go for HAL's suggestion of only capturing changes, but I'd also look at eliminating any options that I do not need -- STORAGE clauses, for example?