# How I can Export ddl of all objects like table, index etc in SYBASE IQ/ SYBASE ASE without using any tools?

Tags: java, schema, sap-iq

I have created a sample program in which I want to get ddl of all objects like table, trigger etc using get_ddl method. When I tried following queries in oracle it worked.

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', TABLE_NAME) FROM USER_TABLES;
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TRIGGER', TRIGGER_NAME) FROM USER_TRIGGERS;
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('VIEW', VIEW_NAME) FROM USER_VIEWS;
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('FUNCTION', OBJECT_NAME) FROM USER_PROCEDURES WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'FUNCTION';
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('PROCEDURE', OBJECT_NAME) FROM USER_PROCEDURES WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE';
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX', INDEX_NAME) FROM USER_INDEXES ;
```

But when I try to create same sample for sybase to get ddl or script of all objects it doesn't work.because get_ddl not supported in sybase database. Can anyone help me to know that whether sybase Iq 15  supports get_ddl methods or there are any other method/way or queries  for creating ddl/script of all objects.

**I want to post it  on SAP forums but all sites are unavailable can anyone suggest me link for post my problem.**

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Please refer this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283452/optimizing-query-dbms-metadata-get-ddl-oracle

Comment: I want Queries only for extract ddl of sybase database.

Answer (score 0):

The ddl for triggers, stored procedures, and views can be pulled from sys.syssource.  Unfortunately IQ doesn't store ddl for other objects

Answer (score 0):

For ase,

Use sybsystemprocs 
Go

sp_helptext (object)
Go

For views,  stored procedures,  and triggers